# Is there a standard unix program that returns a range of numbers

Tags: bash, unix

Im learning shell scripting from an outdated textbook, and it seems to me like it'd be really usefull to have a program that just returns a string of numbers delimited by spaces something like

```
$ range 10 20
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Then, if youre doing a shell script you can have

```
for i in `range 10 20`; do some stuff with numbers in that range;done
```

does such a thing exist, or do I need to write it myself?

Comment: when you say "unix", do you really mean Linux? Or are you really interested in portability to other systems (Solaris, BSD, ...)?

Comment: s/range/seq - replace `range` with `seq` in your example. default separator is newline, to have spaces: `seq -s " " 10 20`

Comment: @naxa Whether it's spaces or newlines does not matter in the `for` loop—or even any general command that splits arguments—unless you've set the IFS differently.

Comment: This question should define what "standard unix program" means to OP.

Comment: I say unix because im learning linux from the book "The Unix Programming Environment" by pike (I know its dated, but I like it).

Comment: As @DavidRivers already commented, you should state in the title and the question your focus is on Linux distributions. The answer you accepted suggests a tool which is NOT a standard Unix program. Several Unix are lacking `seq` as it is not specified by POSIX.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`seq` is part of coreutils.

```
for i in $( seq 1 2 11 ) ; do echo $i ; done
```

Output:

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
```

If you provide only 2 arguments to `seq`, the increment is 1:

```
$ seq 4 9
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: `sed` also has nice options like `-s` to set the separator or `-w` to qualize the width. And you can provide an increment: `seq -w -s ", " 0 5 20` results in

*00, 05, 10, 15, 20*.

Comment: @scai you meant `seq`?

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós Of course, unfortunately I can't edit my comment any more.

Comment: `seq 10 20` might also be a simple example worth adding ;)

Comment: @scai that is awesome, I learnt something new today :) to be honest, I think you should add that as a separate, more detailed answer!

Answer (score 34):

Would Bash suffice?

```
for i in {10..20}; do echo $i; done
```

You can do a lot of things with [brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace). Bash 4 also supports padded ranges, e.g. `{01..20}`.

Note that Bash is *not* considered portable, and not a standard Unix utility. Although you can safely assume that it is installed on most modern Linuxes, don't use this in a script that you plan to run on all kinds of Unix-like machines.

Comment: @Maksim: Although I also prefer this brace expansion, there's also a typical Un*x tool (do very little, but do that well) for that: `seq`. The usage is as in your example: `seq -s " " 10 20`. The `-s` parameter is necessary, because by default the values are separated by `\n`.

Comment: Yeah, Bash isn't "standard" depending on how strict you interpret that. I just find it easier to handle and it doesn't require an extra call.

Comment: @mpy, note that `seq` is a GNU utility, and therefore not a "standard unix program"

Comment: @glennjackman According to http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/seq.1.html... "The seq command first appeared in Plan 9 from Bell Labs.  A seq command appeared in NetBSD 3.0, and ported to FreeBSD 9.0.  This command was based on the command of the same name in Plan 9 from Bell Labs and the GNU core utilities.  The GNU seq command first appeared in the 1.13 shell utilities release."

Comment: Also note that you can do `for i in {001..010}; ... ; done` and it will zero-pad the number to 3 digits.

Comment: @jex That's what I mentioned: *"Bash 4 also supports padded ranges"*.

Answer (score 9):

If you want something strictly portable (i.e. that does not rely on specific bash extensions or commands not specified by POSIX)

```
awk 'BEGIN {for(i=10;i<=20;i++) printf "%d ",i; print}'
```

Comment: Don't you need to add `/dev/null` or `< /dev/null` to that?

Comment: @Scott No, this is not necessary. The POSIX standard ( http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_06 ) specifies: `If the awk program contains no actions and no patterns, but is otherwise a valid awk program, standard input and any file operands shall not be read and awk shall exit with a return status of zero.`

Answer (score 6):

Before 10.7 there was no `seq` on Mac OS X, but [`jot`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=jot&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%207.1-RELEASE&format=html), due to the BSD heritage.

```
jot -- print sequential or random data

...

HISTORY
    The jot utility first appeared in 4.2BSD
```

Example:

```
$ jot - 1 3
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop

```
for ((i = 10; i <= 20; ++i)); do
    printf '%d\n' "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness here something that will work with some older variants of Unix (as long as they have perl installed). Not really elegant.

```
for I in $(perl -e 'print join("\n", 1..10)'); do something with $I; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seq`, or if you don't have that, you can write it yourself:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $# -ge 1 ] || { echo "Usage: seq Number [ Number ]" 1>&2 ; exit 1; }
[ $# -eq 1 ] && { [ $1 -gt 1 ] && ./seq $(($1 - 1)) ; echo $1 ; }
[ $# -eq 2 ] && { [ $(($2 - $1)) -gt 0 ] && ./seq $1 $(($2 - 1)) ; echo $2 ; }
```

Usage:

```
$ ./seq 3
1
2
3
```

Or:

```
$ ./seq 3 7
3
4
5
6
7
```